# launch instagram application from website link in android mobile

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery, html

I have been searching over the internet and I did not get any answer for launching instagram application from website link in android mobile . I have to launch instagram app from my website. My website will have a link to launch instagram application. I tried "instagram://" hooks .. It is working for ios..I did not find anything for android.Please help me out.

Comment: u just want to open instragram in android browser?try this Intent browser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.insta....com"));
startActivity(browser);

Comment: thanks for your reply. This is not android app.. This is html5 website.we can not use intent here